# (Compile-time) unit testing which of several overloads is called

Tags: c++, unit-testing, metaprogramming

Consider the following piece of code:

```
    struct A {};
    struct B : A {};

    bool f(A,A) { /* ... */ }
    bool f(B,B) { /* ... */ }
```

Now suppose I have somewhere something like

```
    // ...
    b = f(x,y);
    // ...
```

I would like to ensure by a (probably compile-time, or alternatively run-time) unit test that a particular overload of `f` is called by this sequence of code. Let's say `f(B,B)` is some specialized, optimized version of `f(A,A)`, so that it is functionally equivalent, yet faster. I cannot determine which function has been called by just looking at the result.

One possibility, of course, is letting `f` set some global flag.

Another possibility is something like

```
   template <class X, class Res> struct Distinguish {
       using Tag = X;
       Res m_res;
       explicit Distinguish (Res res) : m_res (res) { }
       operator Res () const { return m_res; }
   };

   Distinguish<char[1], bool> f (A, A) { /* ... */ }
   Distinguish<char[2], bool> f (B, B) { /* ... */ }
```

and then examine `decltype(f (x,y))::Tag`. Yet that is ugly, since I have to change the signatures of `f`.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Can't you depend on logging mechanism?

Comment: No, I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Idea: Distinguish the functions by adding dummy default arguments of different types? That still changes their signatures, but enables me to use decltype and at the same type does not mess with the types actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Step thru it in a debugger. You might have to put a carriage return before the curly brace in your function definitions.

Comment: I think the asker is interested in an automated, repeatable test, similar to compile-time assertions.

Comment: Debugging does not replace a unit test. Using a debugger will bring clarity for the moment, yet does not prevent me from accidentally changing the behaviour of the code in the future.